# Find intersection of words in two strings in python

Tags: python, string, list, intersection, cpu-word

I have two strings containing words:
`'dan esh gah'` and `'da nesh gah'`

I need the intersection words, which is `'gah'` in this case.

I used this code

```
vocab=['dan esh gah']
gold=['da nesh gah']
s1 = ''.join(vocab)
s2=''.join(gold)

a=[]
track=[]
for k in range(len(s1)+1):
    if k!=0:
        for ka in range(0,len(s1)+1,k):
            if s1[ka:ka+k] in s2:
                track.append((len(s1[ka:ka+k])+1,s1[ka:ka+k]))
intersect=max(track)[1]
print(intersect)
```

but the answer is wrong:

```
sh ga
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `set(s1.split()) & set(s2.split())`

Comment: `'dan esh gah'` is a string with 3 words.

Comment: Yes. That's right. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the *intersection* using [`&`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) on [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) object:

```
>>> s1='da nesh gah'
>>> s2='dan esh gah'

>>> set(s1.split()) & set(s2.split())
set(['gah'])
```

Here, I am firstly converting the string to list of words using [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split). [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) will convert the list to [set object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), on which you can find intersection between two sets using [`&`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection).

If you prefer functional style, you can use [`set().intersection()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) to get the same result:

```
>>> set(s1.split()).intersection(s2.split())
set(['gah'])
```

Comment: Is there a way to know which exact word from the list matched? (I'm using set().intersection()) thanks